# Apple Push Notifications error

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am getting the below email from Apple after pushing the build in iTunes connect for Beta testing.

> Dear developer,
>   We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "MyApp Beta". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>   Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API. 
>   After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
>   Regards,
>   The App Store team

I dont have any code to enable Push notification. To be specific, I am not calling the below methods in my code as well. Not sure why I am getting this email from Apple.

- (void)application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
- (void)application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:
- (void)application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:

Thanks

Comment: So what libraries are you using that do push handling?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't use push notification in your app then please make sure the distribution push notification service should be ***disabled*** in developer account.

[image]